# StackOverflowError when connection to aurora using mariadb java client

Tags: java, sql, mariadb, amazon-aurora

When connecting to an aurora db using the mariadb java client (version 2.7.5) i am getting this error (I only put the first few lines because the entire stack is endless) :

```
Exception in thread "MariaDB-pool-1-appender-2" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.ReadAheadBufferedStream.fillBuffer(ReadAheadBufferedStream.java:131)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.ReadAheadBufferedStream.read(ReadAheadBufferedStream.java:104)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacketArray(StandardPacketInputStream.java:247)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacket(StandardPacketInputStream.java:218)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1539)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1520)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readRequestSessionVariables(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:995)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readPipelineAdditionalData(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1041)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.postConnectionQueries(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:885)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:600)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:501)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:2056)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1541)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1520)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readRequestSessionVariables(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:995)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readPipelineAdditionalData(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1041)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.postConnectionQueries(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:885)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:600)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:501)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:2056)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1541)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1520)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readRequestSessionVariables(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:995)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readPipelineAdditionalData(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1041)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.postConnectionQueries(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:885)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:600)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:501)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:2056)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1541)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1520)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readRequestSessionVariables(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:995)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readPipelineAdditionalData(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1041)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.postConnectionQueries(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:885)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:600)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:501)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:2056)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1541)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1520)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readRequestSessionVariables(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:995)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readPipelineAdditionalData(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1041)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.postConnectionQueries(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:885)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:600)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:501)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:2056)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1541)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1520)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readRequestSessionVariables(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:995)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readPipelineAdditionalData(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1041)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.postConnectionQueries(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:885)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:600)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:501)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:2056)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1541)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1520)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readRequestSessionVariables(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:995)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readPipelineAdditionalData(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1041)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.postConnectionQueries(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:885)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:600)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:501)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:2056)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1541)
at
```

The same code to connect to a mysql is working without any troubles.

My connection URL is as follow :

```
jdbc:mariadb://aurora-url:3306/?autoReconnect=true&sessionVariables=sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES&maxAllowedPacket=260046848&allowLoadLocalInfile=true&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2&maxPoolSize=10&pool
```

Same code with mariadb connector version 3.0.3 and same URL without

> maxPoolSize=10&pool

was working fine on aurora too.

Version of the driver 2.7.5 + aurora without the pool options does not work either.

According to this documentation : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/database/using-the-mariadb-jdbc-driver-with-amazon-aurora-with-mysql-compatibility/ the last version of the mariadb driver is not compatible with aurora. Not sure which version they are talking about since the version 3.0.3 which is that last is working fine.

According to mariadb driver documentation, the support of aurora drop from the version 2.7 -> 3.0.

Comment: The connection string might be prefixed by jdbc:mariadb:aurora

Comment: i am having a similar issue. i am suspecting we are losing sight of the real issue in the IOException that is being handled. whats strange to me is that when i run the code locally in a docker container, it works fine. but when i deploy to kubernetes, i get the error (using exact same connection string)

Comment: @theGuardian When you run the code in a docker container are you still using aurora or an alternative ? Using the prefix jdbc:mariadb:aurora worked for me. Also I think you should use this prefix but only upon a specific version of the Mariadb client (3.0 removed the support if I remember well)

Comment: yes, i am using same exact connection string in the two cases. i am actually pointing to a read-only cluster and so using the :aurora in the protocol errors out.

Answer (score 1):

short answer:

adding the below to the connection string worked for me

```
&usePipelineAuth=false&useBatchMultiSend=false
```

how i got there:

the stack overflow error is masking the true error (the IOException being handled at `org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:2056)`

by removing the `&autoconnect=true` flag from my connection string, the StackOverflowError disappeared and i started to get the below

```
 My-Pool-Name - Exception during pool initialization. | 
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=redacted)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=324732) could not load system variables
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:197)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1394)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89).....
.....
```

then i found below ticket that suggested adding the above mentioned params to connection string https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-824